# How to properly append li to ul using vanilla JavaScript and Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I do want to get all of my messages in my firebase database console. My code is plain JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="collection" id="chatList"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
var chatList = document.getElementById('chatList');
databaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      chatList.appendChild('<li class="collection-repeat">' + childSnapshot.val().message + '</li>');
  })
});
```

[image]

With my code, I only get the last value in the database because I guess it also appends the other `<li>` that is being generated inside the foreach.

What is the proper way to append `<li>` so that it won't also append the other `<li>`?

I know that in jQuery, it can be achieved like this:

```
$('#chatList').append('<li class="collection-repeat">' + childSnapshot.val().message + '</li>')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it's not even working with jQuery ?

Comment: It's working in jQuery @mrid

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild()` is used to append a `node` to an element. But you are trying to append a `string`.

Try using

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
var chatList = document.getElementById('chatList');
databaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var node = document.createElement("li");
        node.className="collection-repeat";
        var textnode = document.createTextNode( childSnapshot.val().message );
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        chatList.appendChild(node);
    })
});
```

Comment: Why not write `node.textContent = childSnapshot.val().message` ?